# multipart form-data doesn't allow apostrophe?

Tags: php, forms

I'm using the following form code:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="process.php" method="POST">
 <input type="text" name="draftTitle"/>
 <textarea name="draftText" class="draftText"></textarea>
 <input type="file" name="uploadfile"/>
 <button class="draftSubmit">Add</button>
</form>
```

As you can see the form contains field for both text and files. When I submit the form with an apostrophe in the textarea nothing get's submitted. In process.php I'm stripping slashes and properly sanitizing the POST data but it seems the problem is related to the from enctype. Any ideas on how to prevent the apostrophe from messing up the syntax?

***UPDATE: This is the output from the form:***

```
-----------------------------276443266232757\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data;
name="MAX_FILE_SIZE"\r\n\r\n4000000\r\n-----------------------------276443266232757\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data;
name="userID"\r\n\r\n2\r\n-----------------------------276443266232757\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data;
name="lineID"\r\n\r\n1\r\n-----------------------------276443266232757\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data;
name="draftTitle"\r\n\r\nThis is my title\r\n-----------------------------276443266232757\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data;
name="uploadfile";
filename=""\r\nContent-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n\r\n-----------------------------276443266232757\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data;
name="draftText"\r\n\r\nIt's my description with an apostrophe in it.\r\n-----------------------------276443266232757--\r\n
```

As you will see there are a few extra fields. I removed them above to simplify the question.

***UPDATE***

I'm using the following code to insert to the database.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO posts (line_id, user_id, stamp_title, element, type) VALUES ('$line_id', '$user_id', '$stamp_title', '$data', '$type')";
mysql_query($query);
```

***Solved:***
I added mysql_real_escape_string and it worked. Thanks to all who helped!

```
$data = mysql_real_escape_string($data);
```

Comment: It calls my attention that you dont have any submit control within your form.  How are you submitting the form?

Comment: I copied that HTML and put it in a test file, pointed it to a php script that just prints all of the POST params, submitted apostrophes everywhere, and everything worked fine.

Comment: @HernanVelasquez I submitted it by pressing "enter" while the focus was in the first text filed.

Comment: sorry yes it has a submit button I just forgot to add that above...just edited it...

Comment: What are you doing with the form data? If you are entering it into the database, then do not stripslashes! Databases need backslashes on quotes... That could be your problem

Comment: Please post some of your PHP code. Multipart forms send single quotations fine, this issue is with your PHP code.

Comment: Using this to parse it: $data = stripslashes($_POST['draftText']);
I'll try without stripslashes but is that safe?

Comment: Are you sure nothing is being sent? Have you checked Firebug or similar to see what is actually sent to the server?

Comment: Do you see anything wrong when you do `var_dump($_POST)`? That'll tell you if the issue is with the POST or something you do to the data.

Comment: Seems you are on to something here...

array(5) { ["MAX_FILE_SIZE"]=> string(7) "4000000" ["userID"]=> string(1) "2" ["lineID"]=> string(1) "1" ["draftTitle"]=> string(4) "test" ["draftText"]=> string(11) "it's a test" }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your form submission is:

```
-----------------------------276443266232757
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="MAX_FILE_SIZE"

4000000
-----------------------------276443266232757
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="userID"

2
-----------------------------276443266232757
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="lineID"

1
-----------------------------276443266232757
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="draftTitle"

This is my title
-----------------------------276443266232757
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="uploadfile"; filename=""
Content-Type: application/octet-stream


-----------------------------276443266232757
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="draftText"

It's my description with an apostrophe in it.
-----------------------------276443266232757--
```

Which is perfectly fine, your apostrophes are there.

However, from this to:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO posts (line_id, user_id, stamp_title, element, type) VALUES ('$line_id', '$user_id', '$stamp_title', '$data', '$type')";
mysql_query($query);
```

Seems to be the issue, since you're using apostrophes in your SQL insert. You should call [`mysqli_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) or [`PDO::quote()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php) (if you have that extension) on each of your input variables.

Answer (score 1):

My observation is, it is not the problem with PHP, but with the rest of the code you are using for either putting the values in database or file. Please post that code also.

I am assuming that you are inserting values to MySql database. To help with it, you can try [Mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) function to prepare it for mysql before inserting.

Comment: $query = "INSERT INTO posts (line_id, user_id, stamp_title, element, type) VALUES ('$line_id', '$user_id', '$stamp_title', '$data', '$type')";
mysql_query($query);

Comment: Try this - $name = mysql_real_escape_string($post['draftText']) and then form the query.

Comment: You should also try checking the actual posted values using fiddler or similar utilities. http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/version.asp